# Why is my class (struct) not being added to the NSMutableArray correctly?

Tags: objective-c, class, ios7, struct, nsmutablearray

I have two (2) classes defined in one .m file:

```
@interface vendorData : NSObject  {  //  <  first class

@public
  NSString *vendor;
  NSString *price;
  NSString *condition;
}
@end
@implementation vendorData

@end
@interface DetailViewController () < UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation DetailViewController  //  <--  second (main) class

//  code for the main class follows
```

I initialize both the class and NSMutableArray like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:100];
vendorData *data = [[vendorData alloc] init];
```

I fill the class data using NSScanner, then put the vendorData object into a NSMutableArray; this is how I'm populating the data object:

```
    NSData *siteHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: siteUrl];
siteHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: siteUrl];  //  get past first page ("searching")
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:siteHTMLData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//  start the search
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:htmlString];
NSString *priceString, *vendorString, *conditionString;
vendorData *data = [[vendorData alloc]init];

do {
   @try {
        
        
        //  find vendor
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<tr  id=\"" intoString:nil];
        scanner.scanLocation += 9;

        [scanner scanUpToString: @"\r\n" intoString: &vendorString];  //  find end of vendor
        data->vendor = vendorString;
        
        //  find price
        scanner.scanLocation += 2;
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<span >$" intoString:nil];  //  find beginning of price
        scanner.scanLocation += 8;
        [scanner scanUpToString: @"</span>" intoString: &priceString];  //  find end of price
        data->price = priceString;
        scanner.scanLocation += 7;
    }
    
    @catch (NSException *exception)  {
        if([[exception reason] isEqualToString: NSRangeException])
            break;
    }
    
    // see if vendor/price is already in array; if so ignore it
    
    NSLog(@"\ndata->vendor: %@,\n->price: %@", data->vendor, data->price);  //  <---------
    [arrayOfPrices addObject:data];  //  add struct to array
    

    
} while (([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) || (scanner.scanLocation > htmlString.length));
```

This is a portion of the log:

> 2014-08-24 11:53:03.154 BookInventoryManager[3741:60b]
> data->vendor: Thriftbooks.comUsed",
> ->price: 1.00
> 2014-08-24 11:53:03.155 BookInventoryManager[3741:60b]
> data->vendor: ValoreBooksUsed",
> ->price: 0.01
> 2014-08-24 11:53:03.155 BookInventoryManager[3741:60b]

and this is what the debugger shows in the *arrayOfPrices* array:

[image]

*Amazon.ca.Marketplace* should be the last entry added to *arrayOfPrices*, but for some reason it appears in each and every element of the mutable array.  Why?

Comment: If you look at the log, you will see that the "dictionary" (I'm assuming you mean the class **vendor**) has the correct data in it; it is not being populated to **arrayOfPrices** like it should (the **vendor** object should go into a different element of the array)

Comment: Yes, I meant the vendor class. You can see in the debugger output that the objects at index 0 and 1 have the same address, i.e. they are the same objects. An array keeps only pointers into its elements, that means that you you add the object at index 0, then modify its properties and add it again at index 1 then both index 0 and index 1 in the array point to the same modified object. - I am quite sure that similar questions have been asked and answered before, but it is a bit difficult to find an exact duplicate.

Comment: @MartinR how do I fix it (see comment I added to gnasher792's answer)

Comment: You have skipped the most important part of the code you should have shown. which is  how you are populating the vendor data. No one can help you without this which is frustrating

Comment: @spokane-dude see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you want to append a element you should create a new instance of the object.

You can create your own custom init to make it easier. Here is an example:

```
@interface vendorData : NSObject  { 

@public
  NSString *vendor;
  NSString *price;
  NSString *condition;
}
-(id) initWithVendor:(NSString) vendor price:(NSString *)price  condition:(NSString *) condition;
@end

@implementation vendorData
-(id) initWithVendor:(NSString) vendor price:(NSString *)price  condition:(NSString *) condition{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.vendor = vendor;
        self.price = price;
        self.condition = condition;
    }
    return(self);
}
@end
```

And here is how you would fill your mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:100];
vendorData *data1 = [[vendorData alloc] initWithVendor:@"Amazon" price:@"31.75" condition: nil];
[arrayOfPrices addObject:data1];
vendorData *data2 = [[vendorData alloc] initWithVendor:@"Ebay" price:@"20.00" condition: @"new"];
[arrayOfPrices addObject:data2];
```

---

EDIT: thank you for updating your post, all you need to do is move the object declaration inside of the do-while loop:

```
do {
vendorData *data = [[vendorData alloc]init];
   @try {
         ...
```

or if you want to use the custom init in my example, use it at like this:

```
do {
   @try {

        //  find vendor
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<tr  id=\"" intoString:nil];
        scanner.scanLocation += 9;
        [scanner scanUpToString: @"\r\n" intoString: &vendorString];  //  find end of vendor

        //  find price
        scanner.scanLocation += 2;
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<span >$" intoString:nil];  //  find beginning of price
        scanner.scanLocation += 8;
        [scanner scanUpToString: @"</span>" intoString: &priceString];  //  find end of price
        scanner.scanLocation += 7;
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception)  {
        if([[exception reason] isEqualToString: NSRangeException])
            break;
    }

    // see if vendor/price is already in array; if so ignore it
    vendorData *data = [[vendorData alloc] initWithVendor:vendorString price:priceString condition: nil];
    NSLog(@"\ndata->vendor: %@,\n->price: %@", data->vendor, data->price);  
    [arrayOfPrices addObject:data];  //  add struct to array


} while (([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) || (scanner.scanLocation > htmlString.length));
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you... moving the object inside the do-while loop fixed it... now I understand mutable arrays... thanks again... :D

Comment: yes basically you were adding the same object, your welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As with most problems, odds are that this is a bug in your code. That's what always should be your first thought, especially when you are doing something that thousands of people have done before: It's a bug in your code.

We don't have all the code. We have one line where you create a vendorData object. We don't see where you set the vendor and price. We have one line where you add a vendorData object to a mutable array, and we see that the mutable array contains the same object twice.

The most obvious explanation would be that you create a vendorData object *once*, then set vendor and price to different values, and always add the same vendorData object to the mutable array. Adding an object to a mutable array adds *that* object, not a copy of it.